# Inserting an UriMatcher

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I am a bit confused with UriMatcher.

```
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, BOOK);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", BOOK_ID);
```

What is actually stored in the path of BOOK?
When update and delete, BOOK_ID will be the only thing to use, then what the use of BOOK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mini primer on urimatcher.  BOOK and BOOK_ID are constant integers that are used by the provider only to determine what code to execute.  BASE_PATH is a string that is passed in by the caller probably the name of the table but the implementation is not strict.  AUTHORITY is a string passed in by the caller com.example.provider.

What happens is the uri comes into the content provider and the urimatcher is used to determine what code to execute by returning the integer.

```
int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
        case TODOS:
            checkColumns(availableRides, projection);
            queryBuilder.setTables(RidesDatabaseHandler.TABLE_RIDES);
            break;
        case TODO_ID:
            checkColumns(availableRides, projection);
            queryBuilder.setTables(RidesDatabaseHandler.TABLE_RIDES);
            // adding the ID to the original query
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(RidesDatabaseHandler.KEY_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case LOCATIONS:
            checkColumns(availableLocations, projection);
            queryBuilder.setTables(RidesDatabaseHandler.TABLE_LOCATIONS);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
```